# A simple line of PHP corrupts Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to implement this code into Wordpress:

```
<?php
    $basename = substr(strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])),0,strlen(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))-4);
?>
```

No matter in which of the Wordpress php files I put this in, it corrupts it. Saying that it cannot find the page. This is very bizarre. Do anyone know why it is behaving like this? Or any direct solutions to how I can add this code to Wordpress?

Note that I am not experienced with PHP so any respond with detail would be appreciated.

Comment: Turn on error reporting.  All will be revealed.

Comment: Since you're new to PHP, I'll be more explicit: add this to the top of the file: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: Okay, I changed $basename to something very unique and had the same problem. Do anyone have wordpress installed? And can add this line of code in any PHP file and see if it works for them?

Comment: I added the error reporting that you suggested but nothing showed up on the page displaying errors. Regardless, im sure Im making a mistake there. Wordpress is killing my mind. Help

Comment: Doesn't wordpress use some basename var itself? aren't you overwriting something that is needed?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In all likelyhood there is either a built-in WP function to do it, or an easier php way.

Comment: Maybe there is too much stuff happening in one line. Try breaking it up into components.

Comment: @Petra, I put this on a WP site in the footer and it didn't break anything.  It also didn't return anything either.

Comment: @JMC How did you insert it? Did you literally copy and paste my code?

Comment: yes. Then added `echo $basename; ` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

This is a parse error.

You need a closing bracket at the end:

```
  $basename = substr(strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])),0,strlen(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))-4)
```

It's a good thing to use a text editor or IDE with syntax highlighting that can reveal such things, they are often difficult to see with the naked eye.

That said, as @JMC Creative points out, this looks very kludgy, and there is bound to be a better way to achieve what you want. What is the goal of this?

Comment: Pekka, that code did not work either. Do you have Wordpress installed so that you can test it yourself? Its very strange that I cant paste it anywhere...

Comment: Also did you remove the semicolon for a reason?

Comment: @Petra what is this line supposed to do in the first place? There is definitely a better solution for this (Edit: No, removing the semicolon was an accident but it should work without)

Comment: It is used for a menu, for the menu to detect which page the visitor is on and insert the correct class for it.

Comment: @Petra If you're on PHP >= 5.2, try `$basename = pathinfo($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"],PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Comment: It could be that you're simply putting the code somewhere that it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

You're over-complicating what you're trying to do.

`$fileName = strtolower(basename(__FILE__, ".php"));`

You may want to use php_self instead of file, it depends on what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
$basename = strtolower( substr(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),0,-4));
```